# Pass Model as a list from View to Controller using ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have trouble trying to send my entire model which actually is a `List<Account>` using ajax call.

Providing the following code:

```
@model List<ValidationAccount>

<input type="button" id="SubmitAccounts" value="Final Proceed">

$("#SubmitAccounts").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/setupAccounts/ActivateAccounts',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(Model),
                success: function (data) {
                    $(body).html(data);
                }, error: function (data) {
                }
            });
        });
```

I've tried using simple **Model** and **@Model** but doesn't work. What can I do in this situation?
(So I want to pass as **data** my model (my List)).

---

**Update**

Method Signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public string ActivateAccounts(List<ValidationAccount> Accounts)
{
    return "Success";
}
```

---

**Update 2**

My model:

```
public class ValidationAccount
    {
        public string Faculty { get; set; }
        public string Programme { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if the data that gets posted is valid JSON?

Comment: Yes. It is. Fortunately.

Comment: Do you have a `form` and inputs for each property?

Comment: no. i use only to diplay some info.

Comment: `'@Model'` is going to return `"System.Collections.Generic.List[YourAssembly.ValidationAccount]"` not the objects in the collection. Since you not modifying anything, why do you need to pass the model back to `ActivateAccounts()`? - just get it from the database again (which will be better performance anyway)

Comment: Well I have specific Accounts in my model that's why I don't want to lose them.

Comment: Why would you _lose them_? Surely whatever code you used generate the collection to render this view can be used again to generate the collection in `ActivateAccounts()`

Comment: Well let me tell you the scenario that happens. I make an ajax call on a page which gives me accounts, and I check some entries (using a checkbox for each account entry) then I hit proceed. When I hit proceed a new view is displayed showing based on some features the checked accounts and its emails. On this view exists a Success button which actually does what I want. So that's why I told you I use the model only to show some "e-mails" then if the success btn is clicked the DB is hit and make some changes.And yes maybe it sounds pretty weird that I want to carry a list of accounts on 2 views.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand, but if you want to post back the whole collection you need to render inputs within a form and serialize to form to JSON. Perhaps you ould just post back an array of the account ID's?

Comment: I'll take into consideration. I guessed I could do a simple trick to send my entire model. But if it cannot be done, I think using an invisible form and filling it with my info would be the best choice.

Comment: Probably not very efficient to send all that extra data. Another option might be to store the collection in session when you call your `proceed` method so you don't need to post back anything.

Comment: @StephenMuecke awesome solution with "session". Please post it as answer to accept it because I solved my problem with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@Model` is going to return the name of the collection such as `"System.Collections.Generic.List[YourAssembly.ValidationAccount]"` not the objects in the collection. You could possibly serialize the collection to ViewBag then post it back (not tested) but it seems an unnecessary performance hit to send the data both ways.

Instead you could store the filtered results from you `Proceed` method in session and retrieve it in the `ActivateAccounts` method to avoid posting anything back.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
data: { Accounts: JSON.stringify('@Model') }
```

and also set `traditional` property to  `true`:

```
data: { Accounts: JSON.stringify('@Model') },
traditional:true
```

### UPDATE:

```
 var accounts= { Accounts: '@Model' };
```

and:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/{controller}/{action}',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(accounts),
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately it doesn't work. My param is still `null`. See update.

Comment: Ok. Progressions made. But instead of 2 items (which actually I display on my view) when the model is sent I get 0. Tx

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the data as `json` first

try

```
var parsedData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); // This will change the model to json
```

then pass the `parsedData` to ajax call

```
$("#SubmitAccounts").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/setupAccounts/ActivateAccounts',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: parsedData,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(body).html(data);
                }, error: function (data) {
                }
            });
        });
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to pass whole of the Model back to controller method is by serializing the form, something like below...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var form = $('#Form1');

 $('#1stButton').click(function (event) {

    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr( 'action' ),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
    } );
  } );
}
```

NB : The button you are using to trigger the event that causes the submit of the form via ajax post should not be of type submit! Else this will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

In your .cshtml, import System.Text.Json, and use it like `@JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.ToList()))`

```
@model IEnumerable<Ticket>
@using System.Diagnostics;
@using System.Text.Json;


@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
<div id="ticketGrid">
 <table >
    <thead> // ...
      <th scope="col">
        <span class="d-flex">
        <button style="all:unset" 
         onclick="toggleOrder(@JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.ToList()))">
        </button>
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Issue.UpdatedOn)
        </span>
      </th> // ...
   </thead>
   <tbody height="80px" class="overflow-y-auto">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
        <tr scope="row"> // ... 
        </tr>

   }
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
}
```

In your Ajax, use `JSON.stringify(your-model)` and `contentType: 'application/json'`

```
<script>
    function toggleOrder(tickets) {

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Ticket/ToggleOrder',
            data: JSON.stringify(tickets),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            // dataType: 'json',
            success: function (viewData) {
                $("#ticketGrid").html(viewData);       
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

In your controller, use

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ToggleOrder([FromBody] List<Ticket> tickets)
{
    // do something ...
    // return Json or PartialView
    // return Json(new { data = ticketsToReturn });
    return PartialView("_TicketGrid", ticketsToReturn.ToList());
}
```